# Angular 2 Adal authentication returns back to starting page

Tags: angular, typescript, adal, adal.js

For my angular app I'm using ADAL and followed the underlying link to set it up.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/26/using-adal-with-angular2/

So on the login page I got a button which redirects to the Azure login page. Login is successfull and it is redirected to the home page, but after a moment, the website refresh and returns to the login, but I'm logged in Azure.
The return always happens to the page from where the procedure started (I tested this by starting from the home page).

In another angular website I developed, ADAL is also used to authenticate to Azure and there everything is working fine and the package versions are all the same.

**Adal Config**

```
  public get getAdalConfig(): any {
    return {
        tenant: environment.AzureTenantID,
        clientId: environment.AzureApplicationID,
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/id_token',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + environment.IISredirectURL,                             // directly return to login after logoff
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    }
}
```

Do anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Cant really tell with the amount of code you have shared.
My guess would be that you are not calling handleWindowCallback() which deciphers the id_token and stores it for you in either local or session storage based on your confoguration.